# Delivery report for Sumit-Multi

Tags: java, smpp, jsmpp

We are using [jsmpp](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp) library with [SmppSm](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/user-guide.htm), here's the scenario

1. create session and bind as `transmitter`
2. register `MessageRecieverListener`
3. send `SubmitMulti` command

we were expecting to receive delivery report, but We didn't, we also search if `SMPP` support delivery report for `Submit-Multi`
here's my code

```java
SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();
return session.connectAndBind("127.0.0.1",
 2775,
 new BindParameter(BindType.BIND_TRX,
  "smppclient1",
  "password",
  "cp",
  TypeOfNumber.UNKNOWN,
  NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,
  null));

Address[] addresses = new Address[] {
 new Address(TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "628176504657"),
  new Address(TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "628176504658")
};

session.setMessageReceiverListener(new MessageReceiverListenerImpl());

Address[] addresses = new Address[] {
 new Address(TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "628176504657"),
  new Address(TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "628176504658")
};

result = session.submitMultiple("CMT",
 TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "1616",
 addresses,
 new ESMClass(), (byte) 0, (byte) 1, TIME_FORMATTER.format(new Date()), null,
 new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.SUCCESS_FAILURE), ReplaceIfPresentFlag.DEFAULT,
 new GeneralDataCoding(Alphabet.ALPHA_DEFAULT, MessageClass.CLASS1, false), (byte) 0,
 "jSMPP simplifies SMPP on Java platform".getBytes());
```

But we guess that `SMPP` doesn't support such thing as the delivery report contains only `message-id` and `message-state` where no information about receiver info, that makes no sense in `submit-multi`

Comment: did you receive delivery reports for each destination in `submit_multi`? Is there any specific reference on that SMPP is not supporting it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use transceiver mode to receive the response

Comment: Thanks for interesting but I've already done this , i am binding as a `BIND_TRX`